# Relationship between degrees and number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Why 
$(\sum_{v_iv_j \in E(G)} \sqrt{d(i)d(j)} )(\sum_{v_iv_j \in E(G)}\frac{1}{ \sqrt{d(i)d(j)}}) \ge m^2$ 
is true? I mean, how to proof it?
$m$ is number of edges and $d_1,d_2,\dots ,d_n$ is degree sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_(n-dimensional_Euclidean_space)) for $N$-dimensional space
$$
(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_N^2)(y_1^2 + \cdots + y_N^2) \geq (y_1x_1 + \cdots + y_Nx_N)^2.
$$
All degrees $d(i)$ and their square roots are positive, thus you can safely assume $\sqrt{d(i)d(j)} = x_k^2$ and $1/\sqrt{d(i)d(j)} = y_k^2$.

**Note**: For $n$ vertices there are $N = n(n-1)/2$ possible pairs of vertices. It is always the case $N \geq m$ with equality if and only if the graph is full.

Comment: so, it should be $x^2_m$, not $x^2_n$?

Comment: @BAnt in the inequality I wrote, $n$ designates number of pairs of points. I will correct it to capital $N$ to avoid confusion. It should be $N=n(n-1)/2$ and $N$ can be greater than $m$ if graph is not fully connected